# how to read memory stream of a pdf file and open it in nodejs

Tags: node.js, electron, memorystream

Node Version: 5.7.1

Platform: 64-bit (Windows)

Hi,

I am a newbie in working with node. I have built an app in electron (which uses node internally) which communicates with a .net restful service to fetch data from db and display it on the screen. One of the data has a pdf path on the server which i read onto the server and convert it into the memory stream and send it to the client app.

The issue is how can i read this memory stream in node js and open the pdf file on my windows machine through adobe acrobat reader which is installed on my windows machine? Here is a sample code which i already tried :

```
var optionsGetPDF= {
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 8080,
       path: '/GetPDFDoc?docid=' + docid,
       method: 'GET'
};

var memStream = new memorystream(null, { readable: false });
http.request(optionsGetPDF, function (res) {
     res.pipe(memStream);
     res.on('end', function () {
          alert(memStream.toString().length)
     });
}).end();
```

So here I am getting the pdf file in the form of a memorystream and I just tried to alert the length to confirm, which is working fine. Now I want this memory stream to be again converted back to a PDF and then open it in the adobe acrobat installed on my windows machine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Shobhit

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to just save it as a file and then open it?

Comment: @Paul  actually the file itself is saved as a PDF which i am trying to fetch from a remote server location, so based on the server path location (which i get from the DB) , my restful service reads the pdf file and converts it into the memory stream and sends to the client . Even if i do it considering it as a file, I am not sure how to do that ?

Comment: I see, that wasn't clear to me when I read your question.  I'll cobble together an answer shortly.

Comment: I totally glossed over the "electron app" part of your question.  My mistake.  From the docs, you can control the download using DownloadItem:

http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/download-item/

Which implies that a link to the URL should work as expected otherwise.  I've not tried this, though

Comment: @Paul Thanks. If you could advise me as a javascript developer may be just on the part how do we read stream of file and convert that stream back to its original state , that could also help me, as i have been able to get the file's stream from the service with correct length onto the client side. What is getting difficult is what needs to be done after that to display that file to the user. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: Electron gives you access to the user's file system, so the easiest thing to do would be to create a writeable stream and write it to disk via pipe.  something like you did with the memstream, just with fs.createWriteStream(https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options).  Once it's on disk, if you have the path, you can open it using the electron shell:  `shell.open('path/to/file');`